# Remember skype image opening program in windows 10

Tags: images, skype, file-association, windows-10

I have upgraded to windows 10 and skype started asking which image viewing program to use when you click on the image someone sent to you. The problem is that I cannot figure how to "remember" this choice, it asks each time.

[image]

Usually there is a checkbox to remember the choice, but not in this case.

Comment: i have multiple applications that does that, mp3tag and utorrent for exemple. Win10 seems to have changed the behavior when an app wants to open a file externally.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on that file (.jpeg, for example) and selected Properties -> Opens with -> Select your preferred application? Does Skype still prompt you, even after that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by setting the default viewer as Windows Photo Viewer in PC Settings / System / Default apps instead of "Photos" of W10.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the default image viewer via PC Settings / System / Default apps.

Comment: It is set by default already... And you can see from screenshot it shows this default app on top in a special manner

Comment: same with me, if i double click on a file from windows explorer the same type it opens up properly