# Microsoft Edge keeps taking over PDF file open/association

Tags: windows-10, adobe-acrobat, file-association, adobe-reader

Every few days the file association for PDFs on my Windows 10 machine switches to Microsoft Edge.

I then right click on a PDF, choose "Open With -> Choose Another App", select Acrobat from the list, and check "Always use this app to open .PDF files".

Then for a few days it sticks, but always winds up going back to Microsoft Edge.  I haven't figured out a pattern to suggest when/why this happens.  It just does and is very annoying.

Does anyone have an idea of why this happens or how to permanently fix it?

Comment: It's the end of a long day, so bear with me… Trash Microsoft Edge and work with another browser…

Comment: I don't work with it but regardless that's not a constructive comment.

Comment: I agree. But when there is nothing better, this would be a fallback. Now a little bit more constructive, but may be completely wrong… could it be related to some automatic action or synching?

Comment: Are you in the Insider Program? I find this tends to happen during a Windows update, which might be happening frequently if you're getting the Insider builds.

Comment: @BrianDuddy no I'm not.

Comment: You could try : https://superuser.com/a/1224671/235752

Answer (score 4):

This is a list of methods to stop Edge from taking over PDF.
Hopefully one of them will work for you.

**Method 1: Using Settings**

- Go to *Start > Default Programs > Choose default apps*
- Scroll down to `.pdf`
- If "Microsoft Edge" is listed on the right, click it and change to Adobe or else

**Method 2: Using Context Menu**

- Right-click any `.pdf`
- Select *Open with > Choose another*
- Select the desired app, e.g. Adobe Acrobat Reader.
  If it is not listed, you will need to browse to its `.exe` file.
- Click OK

**Method 3: Using the Control Panel**

- Go to *Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs >
  Associate a file type or protocol with a program*
- Locate and click `.pdf`
- Click on *Change Program* at the top right corner
- Select your desired program, e.g. Adobe Acrobat Reader or `.exe`
- Click OK

**Method 4: Using Registry Editor**

- Start `regedit`
- Navigate to

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Repository\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.18362.267.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Capabilities\FileAssociations
  ```

  (the key might change with future Edge versions)
- Double-click the `.pdf` key and copy its value, probably
  `AppXd4nrz8ff68srnhf9t5a8sbjyar1cr723`
- Go to the following location
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppXd4nrz8ff68srnhf9t5a8sbjyar1cr723`
- In the right-pane, create two string values (REG_SZ) named `NoOpenWith`
  and `NoStaticDefaultVerb` with empty values
- Exit the Registry Editor
- Use "Default Programs" to re-associate the file type with your preferred program.

**Method 5: Renaming Edge Launcher Files**

- Navigate to the following directory:
  `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`.
  It should contain the file `MicrosoftPdfReader.exe`.
- Take ownership of the folder
- Rename the files `MicrosoftEdge.exe` and `MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe`
  (if the latter exists) to some other name.
- Reboot.

Comment: Thanks! 1-4 are not permanent (edge is taking over pdf again), but method 5 could be permanent.

Comment: Method 5 might need repeating every major Windows update such as 1903, 1909 etc.

Comment: Every major update they change it again without asking.  If they could please leave it alone when I already have Adobe Acrobat Pro installed....

Answer (score 2):

According to this Microsoft Community question -> [How to disable Microsoft Edge as default pdf program](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_internet-insider_spartan/how-to-disable-microsoft-edge-as-default-pdf/57f12003-4f05-481f-bdfb-c0b892f592f6?page=1), this was/is a common problem.  Some people have found relief doing the following:

> Go to 'Settings'
>
> Select 'Apps & Features'
>
> Select 'Programs and Features' (Under 'Related Settings')
>
> Select 'Control Panel Home'
>
> Select 'Make a file type always open in a specific program'
>
> Scroll down and highlight .pdf file type
>
> Select 'Change program'
>
> Select desired program

Comment: Why 3 steps to get to the control panel? Why not just open the control panel directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the latest Adobe Reader(DC), Also try the following:

Open Settings > Apps > Default Apps > Choose default apps by file type (at the bottom of the page) > scroll way down to .pdf and choose abode acrobat reader DC.

Comment: Sorry, both does not work ---- 1.: I always have the latest version of Adobe Reader (currently 19.012.20040) ---- 2.: Changing the default app is what I currently do every time when Edge is hijacking PDF again.

Comment: Try this then : Open Settings > Apps > Under Apps & Features scroll down and click on Microsoft Edge > Choose Advanced Options > Scroll Down and Reset it.
And then again set adobe DC as the default .pdf and .pdx reader