# Windows 10 keeps undoing my choice for PDF app

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-reader

By default, Windows 10 (Pro) seems to open `.pdf` files in Edge - yuck! I picked Acrobat Reader instead - and for a while, it seemed to work.

Then, however, I suddenly get a message in the message center "An app association has been reset" (or something like that - mine is in German) - without any further explanation - and now Win10 is *again* opening all my `.pdf` files in Edge.

I keep doing this - sometimes more than once a day - but I can't seem to get Win10 to **simply ACCEPT** my choice of Acrobat Reader over Edge - this is **HIGHLY ANNOYING** !

Is there any way or hack to get Win10 to finally **SHUT UP** and just accept that I prefer opening my `.pdf` files in Acrobat Reader?

Comment: Are you using an insider build?

Comment: This is an (annoying) behaviour associated with updates, which is probably why @JohnStoneman asked his question.  As to how to block it?  Don't know.  Still, this is a dupe...

Comment: @JohnStoneman: no, just the regular RTM build

Comment: I have utilized every version of Windows 10 from 1507 through 1703, and although I like the OS overall I have always found the new interface to set your default applications to be a bit unreliable.  Typically, I get the best results by navigating to `Control Panel > Default Programs > Set your default programs`, then choosing Acrobat Reader from the list of `Programs` on the left and choosing `Set this program as default` on the right-hand side.  That seems to retain the default PDF file type association, at least until the next Feature Update is released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like you might've already done this, but here it is anyway. https://techforluddites.com/windows-10-change-the-default-programs-for-opening-files/

There **is** a regedit which you can do which you should probably do: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/edge-hijack-pdf-htm-associations/

seems like other people are having this problem.

EDIT: duplicate of [Microsoft Edge keeps taking over PDF file open/association](https://superuser.com/users/379161/baldrickk)

[1](https://superuser.com/users/379161/baldrickk): [Microsoft Edge keeps taking over PDF file open/association](https://superuser.com/questions/1015934/microsoft-edge-keeps-taking-over-pdf-file-open-association), as mentioned by [@Baldrickk](https://superuser.com/users/379161/baldrickk)

Comment: Unfortunately, even all these "solutions" don't really work long term - I'm back again at the point where every couple of days, Win 10 resets my choice of a PDF reader back to MS Edge :-( :-( :-( And this is called "progress" in software.....

Comment: Hmm, that sucks! Only thing I can recommend is either posting on the Microsoft forums or hard resetting Windows