# Edge keeps hijacking PDF extensions

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-reader, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge is constantly changing the PDF file association from Adobe to Edge.

I change it manually back to Adobe Reader, and a few days later, it is again associated with Microsoft Edge. Windows 10, all updates are installed.

I know this topic is already discussed, but I found no answer which helps. It is May 2020 and this problem still persists. Please, someone can help!?

Comment: how did you change your default? going into the settings or selecting 'open with' option after right clicking the file?

Comment: Go to the detailed Associations.  Start, Settings, Apps, Default Apps, and then,  scroll down the right hand side to see "Choose Apps by File Type" .  Click on that, scroll down for PDF and other Adobe PDF types. Associated these with Acrobat and you should be good to go

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Edge keeps taking over PDF file open/association](https://superuser.com/questions/1015934/microsoft-edge-keeps-taking-over-pdf-file-open-association)

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately not. I googled it already long before. This problem is on my PC me since years and it's getting worse now.

Comment: @Sanu_012 I go into settings. I change it, but Edge is changing it back in a few days.

Comment: @John That does no work, unfortunately. When I change the .pdf association to Adobe Reader, then in a few days, it is changed back to Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I have two production machines - one with Adobe Reader, one with Acrobat Pro and both associate properly. I have an Insider machine with Reader and it was associating with Edge. I set PDF, PDX and PDFXML to Adobe in detailed settings by File Type. I checked Settings by Protocol and it was set to Adobe. As soon as I did that, correct associations took hold. I restarted the computer and the association held. The method above has always worked for me. You may need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link.

Comment: Thanks @John, I will try a Repair Instal!

Comment: This is indeed a huge issue. Ever since the new Chrome/Edge it keeps stealing the PDF association. So annoying. It remains unchanged until I open Edge, then it's back to square one.

Comment: @t3chb0t yes, same here. Problem unsolved sine many years, Nothing helped so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a sustainable solution. It's not enough to set another app as a default one as there are still settings that'll override it.

In order to fix that, go to:

> Settings > Apps > Default Apps > Set defaults by app

[image: steps]

Then **find each app that can handle a PDF and set it to your app** like Adobe or Foxit. While updating those settings you'll see that each of them will still have Edge as handler despite some other app being the default handler.

Isn't it well designed? :P

On my PC I'm using Foxit Reader and ACDSee so everytime I set Foxit Reader *in the obvious way* as the default handler, ACDSee replaced it with itself which probably was incorrect as Edge would overwrite with itself so I was back to square one. After updating all apps one by one it didn't happen again.