# Windows 10 keeps asking which program to use to open already associated file types

Tags: windows-10, file-association

Windows keeps bugging me with this dialogue. Asking me to choose program to open file types I have already associated before (like .pdf, .txt files, .cs).
Is there a fix?

[image]

Comment: Did you at least once choose the proper application and checked the box in the lower left.? It should be gone afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: an answer to test : https://superuser.com/a/1224671/235752